# German Citizenship Application for Spouse

Tags: germany, citizenship, blue-card, residence-cards, german-citizens

My husband has been living in Germany for almost 7 years now. He came as a student, worked on a blue card job and now has PR as well. He should now be eligible to apply for citizenship (with the German b1 exam result).

I have been in Germany for almost 5 years now. I studied for 2.5 years and since then worked here with a blue card job. I am currently waiting for my PR appointment. I also have a German b1 certificate. We have been married for 1.5 years.

When my husband applies for his citizenship, can I also apply together with him? Or do I need to wait for my 2 years of marriage to complete first?

The waiting time in Berlin is also long. So is it possible that my husband applies for the citizenship now and I can submit a supplementary application separately once my 2 years of marriage have been completed?

Answer (score 3):

This is often a *discretionary decision* (Ermessungsentscheidung) of the official accepting the application – the first step of which is a consultation appointment.

Based on the fact that the Berlin service states that for applications made **together** shorter deadlines apply (how short is probably again a matter of discretion), you should apply together.

In the worst case they will only say that the second one is unlikely to succeed.

> [Einbürgerung - Verleihung der deutschen Staatsangehörigkeit beantragen - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/318998/)
> **Voraussetzungen**
> …
>
> - 3 Jahren, wenn Sie seit mindestens zwei Jahren mit einer Deutschen oder einem Deutschen verheiratet sind oder eine Lebenspartnerschaft geschlossen haben
> - **Wenn Ihre Ehefrau** oder Ihr Ehemann oder Ihre Kinder **zusammen mit Ihnen einen Antrag stellen, gelten kürzere Fristen**.
>
> > **Prerequisites**
> > …
> >
> > - 3 years if you have been married to a German person for at least two years or have entered into a civil partnership
> > - **If your wife** or husband or children **apply with you, shorter deadlines apply**.